# Replace words in string with values of string array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, string

I have the following string with placeholders

```
'test {{1}} this {{2}} {{3}}'
```

these placeholders later should be replaced in same order by the values from input fields

```
['now', 'code', 'block']
```

so the final string looks like this

```
'test now this code block'
```

what's the best approach here?

Comment: [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) would be a good option for this. Have you tried anything so far to solve this, are you able to share your attempt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) on your string with a regular expression to match the digits between the `{{` and `}}` characters. Then, using the replacement function, which will fire for each digit that is matched, you can return the new value to replace the `{{N}}` occurrence with, which will be the value of the current digit `-1` from your array of values.

```js
const arr = ['now', 'code', 'block']; 
const str = 'test {{1}} this {{2}} {{3}}';
const res = str.replace(/{{([^}}]+)}}/g, (_, d) => arr[d-1]);

console.log(res);
```

Regex explanation for `/{{([^}}]+)}}/g`:

- `{{` - Match the literal characters `{{` in your string
- `([^}}]+)` - Continue matching one or more characters that aren't `}}` and capture them in a group (the `(` and `)` forms a capturing group for your digit)
- `}}` - match the literal `}}` characters
- `/g` - The global flag means match all occurrences of this pattern throughout your string.

In this case, the first argument to the replacement function is the entire match itself (ie: `{{N}}`) which we ignore with `_`, and the second argument is the capturing group we formed that has your digit.

Comment: thank you, this works best for dynamically added placeholders and fields

Comment: https://regexper.com/#%2F%7B%7B%28%5B%5E%7D%7D%5D%2B%29%7D%7D%2Fg

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the array and replace using reg ex.

```js
let temp = 'test {{1}} this {{2}} {{3}}';

let arr = ['now', 'code', 'block'];

arr.forEach(el =>
{
  temp = temp.replace(/{{[0-9]}}/, el);
});

console.log(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a loop that iterates over the items in the array:

```js
let text = 'test {{1}} this {{2}} {{3}}';
const keywords = ['now', 'code', 'block'];

for (let i = 1; i < keywords.length + 1; i++) {
  text = text.replace(`{{${i}}}`, keywords[i-1]);
}

console.log(text);
```

Comment: For a better user experience, please do not use the alert function in your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

@NickParsons solution refers
Here is another regular expression you could use matching:

- the literal opening string `{{`,
- any length of `\d` and capture them.  `[arg 2]` or `_`
- the literal closing string `}}`

The combined match will be `[arg 1]` or `i`

```js
const
      str = 'test {{1}} this {{2}} {{3}}',
      words = ['now', 'code', 'block'],
      
      newStr = str.replace(/{{(\d+)}}/g, (_, i) => words[i-1]);
      
console.log( newStr );


//WORKSHEET
str.replace(
    /{{(\d+)}}/g,     //The regular expression
      (...x) =>       //Put all args in an array
      console.log(x)  //Output the array
);
```